# evince-thumbnailer uses excessive CPU and memory

Tags: performance, evince

I have the well-known problem with evince-thumbnailer, while I was working with tex. No thumbnail created for a .ps and a .dvi file. CPU -> 100% and it ate memory (~500 MB) until I stopped the process in the system monitor. I disabled evince-thumbnailer for now, but my question is: How do I get my 500 MB memory back??

Comment: Do you mean RAM or harddrive memory? If it's the latter, I guess there is a folder somewhere, where evince stores the thumbnails

Comment: I installed okular and uninstalled evince, after failing to find a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Try closing Nautilus (file manager) windows. I closed a Nautilus window showing a  [loading thumbnail icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF5Kl.png) for a PDF file, and just as I closed the window, the `evince-thumbnailer` process closed with it.

Unfortunately, when I open the same directory in Nautilus, `evince-thumbnailer` launches again, but at least closing Nautilus seems like a temporary option.

Answer (score 1):

Running `killall evince-thumbnailer` will stop any currently running or stuck processes, or you could just reboot. You'll get the memory back when those processes exit.

Comment: Thanks for you help! I tried this, but unfortunately the memory did not come back, even after restart.